# Does Linq to Entities 4.0 have Fulltext capabilities?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Just wanted to know if Linq to entities 4.0 have fulltext search capabilities? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no specific operators or support for full text directly in EF v4.0.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is a server option.

Anyways, if it does not (in EF), nothing stops you from calling the required SQL directly.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using custom stored procedures for my Sql Server 2008 FullText capabilities (eg. `CONTAINS(.. .. )`. Of course, EF can call stored procedures.

This is an option you can leverage off. Works great for L2S and/or EF.

HTH.